# Using an if statement to fill a matrix

Tags: matlab, if-statement, matrix

I have a .csv file which includes two columns and each column has a matrix of size 68x1. In order to read the file I use this code:

```
filename1= 'myfile.csv';
[d1,tex]= xlsread(filename1);
b=d1(:,1);
```

I would like to take some values using `if`. I have written :

```
if b<=4.5&&b<60
    X=2*b+5
elseif b>=60
    X=3*b-6
end
```

However, it doesn't work. How can I do this?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please clarify what you are doing with your `if` statement and why it doesn't work. Do you get errors, are the results incorrect, does your computer explode...? Please [edit] the post to be more specific.

Answer (score 3):

In your example, `b` is a vector. The statement `b <= 4.5` outputs a logical vector, which can't be used with the short-circuit double ampersand `&&` and another logical vector.

I'm also going to assume you had a typo, because `b<60` is always true if `b<=4.5`, I think you meant `b>=4.5`.

You have two options:

1. Put this in a loop

   ```
   for ii = 1:numel(b)
       if b(ii) >= 4.5 && b(ii) < 60
           X(ii) = 2*b(ii) + 5;
       elseif b >= 60
           X(ii) = 3*b(ii) - 6;
       end
   end
   ```
2. The more MATLAB-esque way would be to take advantage of vectorisation, note the single ampersand `&`:

   ```
   X = NaN( size(b) );
   X( b >= 4.5 & b < 60 ) = 2*b + 5;
   X( b >= 60 ) = 3*b - 6;
   ```